# Why is sign bit ON for positive numbers in Intel 8086 assembly language?

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm working in Dosbox on ubuntu assembly language. My program has only this line:

```
mov al, 150 ;(not -150)
```

When I use debugger, it shows the value of FLAG register as 0202 which means the sign bit is ON. The same happens for -150. I'm confused why the sign bit is set for a positive number?

Comment: `MOV` doesn't alter the FLAGS

Comment: Hint: what range of signed integer fit in an 8-bit register?  Hint 2: [`mov` doesn't affect flags.](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOV.html).  Hint 3: use a debugger which decodes the FLAGS register for you, like gdb :)  See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info

Comment: But the value of FLAGs updates with each line. Let me send you an example

Comment: You are probably reading the debug window wrong. Possibly you looked at the FLAGS prior to the MOV as they were set by a previous instruction.

Comment: Initially the flag is 0200. Then the line mov al, 150 executes and flag becomes 0202. Why is it changing after this line?

Comment: You should check your debugger to see if FLAG was set by an instruction before the MOV. MOV won't alter it.

Comment: Are you sure you executed MOV in the debugger? Most debuggers will highlight the current instruction but highlighs it before executing the instruction.

Comment: Yes I executed it. But as @MichaelPetch pointed out, MOV does not alter flags, then how can i read the FLAG values?

Comment: Use an instruction after the MOV that tests the value. Like [_TEST_](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/TEST.html)  `test al, al` . This will bitwise AND _AL_ with itself effectively setting SF, ZF, and PF based on the value in _AL_

Comment: So now the initial value is 0200, then 'mov al, 150' returned 0202 and finally 'test al, al' gives 0286 (which means sign bit is ON). I'm doing something really wrong here I think

Comment: Because the upper bit of the value 150 (decimal) is 1 (150 decimal = binary 10010110 ) so SF (sign flag) will be equal to 1 since bit 7(the highest bit) is set. It is up to your code whether to use the sign flag or not. An 8 bit value in a register can be seen as an unsigned value 0 to 255 AND as a signed value -128 to 127. The bit pattern 10010110 represents both the unsigned value 150 and signed value -106.

Comment: What actual debugger are you using?  Does DOSBOX have one built in (so you could debug a bootloader or something)?

Comment: If you were to change `mov al, 150` to `mov al, -106` you'd get the exact same instruction generated

Comment: @PeterCordes : DOSBox can be compiled with an internal debugger, but I suspect that the OP is running a debugger application in DOSBox (Like Turbo Debugger, Codeview, debug.exe which are the more popular ones).

Comment: I use pwb command

Comment: Microsoft CodeView is the debugger i'm using currently

Comment: As for the change from 200 to 202 on. Bit 1 (second lowest bit) is considered **reserved**. Possibly being used by the debugger itself. Since it is reserved you shouldn't rely on the value of that bit meaning anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The x86 and pretty much every CPU currently in use uses 2's complement signed arithmetic.

A byte has 8 bits.
That means it can store 256 different value (2<sup>8</sup>).
127 of those are positive and 128 are negative and one is zero.
To test whether a byte is negative you test the Most Significant Bit (MSB). If this bit is 1 it is deemed to be negative, if it is zero it is deemed to be positive.

The encoding of a 150 in a byte is `1001 0110` ergo it is deemed to be negative.
In fact you can interpret the value as 150 only if you don't allow negative numbers. If you do then the byte holds -106.

This is called signed overflow and the OF flag will detect for this if you're doing calculations using instructions that affect the flags.

**MOV does not affect the flags**
There is something amiss in your question though because `MOV` does not affect the flags, check out the `modif_f` column in: http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32-abc.html
The flags show the state of the CPU as per the last instruction that changed those particular flags.
Some instructions only change a subset of the flags.
You need to step back in your code and look at the last instruction that affected the flags.

Answer (score 2):

The sign bit is *not* on for positive numbers.

What's going on is `al` only holds eight bits of data, and the sign bit is the high bit. Interpretation of values in registers as signed or unsigned is all in your head. If you read the sign bit as a sign bit, you have indicated the register is signed, yielding a range of 127 to -128. 150 is outside that range, so it rolled over.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are overflowing. On al you can have only numbers from 0 to 127, any greater overflows and becomes negative.
In fact the assembly allows that because al is not negative nor possitive. it just is. But if you know you will use signed ones you should not overflow it on the load.
In other words, you are storing 150 in unsigned form, and after that the system is actually transforming that to the signed value which is not actually 150.
in fact is..-106 the value you actually are setting into AL (as signed)
Now why you do not notice this or it complains?
Because it does not know if the value is signed or not (not sure assembly can notice that)
and it will depend on the instruction you use to make anything to it, on how the al is used.
(in fact for addition does not matter it works the same) but is for multipliation or division if maters or not.
Or for whatever parser you use to show.

Comment: If you're interpreting an 8-bit value as signed, it can be -128 .. 127, not 0 to 127.  If you interpret it as unsigned, the range of representable values is 0 to 255.  And no, the computer doesn't know or care which; it's up to the programmer (or compiler) to use instructions that look at the relevant FLAGS, or that use cbw / idiv vs. mov ah,0 / div, and so on.

Comment: when i said "you can have only numbers from 0 to 127" I mean as positive values. and 150 is beyound so explaining that it causes an overflow if he tries to see that as a negative.

Comment: Then [edit] your answer to say exactly that.  (Also use paragraphs to break up the major concepts / points).  BTW, `0` is neither positive nor negative.  You can describe the 0..127 part of the signed range as non-negaitve.